# Wordpress login form alignment

Tags: wordpress, css

How to modify this code to align login form at top not at center.

```
***** custom_login.css *****
/* Change background image and font family */
body {
  background-image: url(background.png);
  font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

/* Change Width and Height of Logo Image + Add Custom Image File */
.login h1 a {
  background-image: url(logo.png);
  width: 213px;
  height: 97px;
  background-size: 213px 97px;
}

/* Add a few changes to the color and style of form itself */
.login label {
  color: #454545;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login form .input {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.login #backtoblog a, .login #nav a {
  color: #4da28f;
}

.wp-core-ui .button-primary {
  background: #4da28f;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no elements that put your login format the center of the screen.
Maybe there are some .js (scripts) files that changes it!

You can take a look here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp